# How do I get gradle 7 to work in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I am having some troubles with setting up a project with gradle 7.1. I can't go below 7 because Fabric Loom 0.8+ needs gradle 7+.

The Intellij IDEA log: https://controlc.com/1c0be753

Using Gradle 7.1 and Java 16

Answer (score 2):

See [the related comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-245303#focus=Comments-27-4870278.0-0) in IntelliJ IDEA bug tracker and [this](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/17612) bug request on Gradle GitHub. The exception could be caused by the filesystem (FAT) and is fixed in Gradle 7.2

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: [Accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) this answer would be the best gratitude